# How to make scrapy print log msg in cmd?

Tags: python, scrapy

I set up a scrapy project and run by scrapy crawl xxx.
I do not see any ouotput in cmd,however log msgs does write to the log file.

I am using log like below:

```
from scrapy import log

def Pipe(...):
    ....
    log.msg("Actor_id: %s wrote to database" % (actor.id,),
                level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
```

How can I make it works?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `parse` command line and debug together when I built my robot. 
More information click [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#logging)

```
self.log("content goes here")
```